# Insert cat_id & cat_name into posts table

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to insert category id and title into posts table.Check bellow image.

- [category table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHpJ3.png)
- [posts table where i want to insert my category id and table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBWQ9.png)

Now my code is

```
<?php
  include 'db.php';
?>
<form action="<?Php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="title" required="">
  <input type="text" name="content" required="">
  <select name="category">
    <?php
      $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `category`");
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" name="add">Add Blog</button>
</form>
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    @$title = $_POST['title'];
    @$category = $_POST['category'];
    @$content = $_POST['content'];
    @$date = date("D M Y");

    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `image`, `title`, `date`, `cat_id`, `cat_name`, `short_description`, `content`) VALUES  (NULL, 'NO_IMAGE', '".$title."', '".$date."', '".$cat_id."', '', '', '".$content."')");
    echo "success!";
  }
?>
```

Now how can i add insert category id, title into posts cat_id, cat_name using select option or other option are available.

Thanks

Comment: Use jquery. You will have more control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I do not encourage reinventing html, you could use the following to get what you want.

```
   <option value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>:<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
   <?php echo $row['title']; ?></option>
```

You could then get:

```
$selectedcategory= $_POST['category'];
$categoryarray = split(':', $selectedcategory);
```

Now you have both the category id and category name in $categoryarray.

```
$cat_name = $categoryarray[0];
$cat_id = $categoryarray[1];
```

Comment: Working. Thanks @Mawia